# applescript error "invalid date and time date"

Tags: applescript, icalendar

Fellas,

I'm an AppleScript newbie. I want to add many events to an iCal calendar. All the events should be all-day-events so they have no start time or duration. I have the dates in a text file, one on each line. But I just copied them over into the script as a string. Here's my code (shortened the list of dates):

```
set input to "03.01.2015
16.01.2015
30.01.2015
13.02.2015
20.11.2015
04.12.2015
18.12.2015"

repeat with datum in paragraphs of input
    tell application "Calendar" to tell calendar "Müll"
        make new event with properties {start date:date datum, summary:"Gargabe", allday event:true}
    end tell
end repeat
```

The error I get from the Apple Script Editor is

```
Invalid date and time date (item 1 of every paragraph of 03.01.2015
16.01.2015
30.01.2015
...
```

Now, I'm running OS X in English but my locale is set to Germany. (Would've loved to post a screenshot of the corresponding Preferences screen but don't have enough reputation here on stackoverflow.)

Anyone with a hint for me what's going wrong here?
Thanks so much in advance!

(Running on OS X 10.10.1 here, btw.)

Comment: According to [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472245/applescript-to-create-set-ical-events), the date Applescript is expecting to see depends entirely on the region or date format you selected in System Preferences on your Macintosh.  Is "`16.01.2015`" the correct format?

Comment: Yes, System Preferences shows that dd.mm.yyyy is a correct date it can understand.

Answer (score 0):

10.8.5

I changed my settings to match your region:

```
repeat with datum in paragraphs of input
    set datum to date (datum as string)
    tell application "Calendar" to tell calendar "Home"
        make new event at end with properties {summary:"Gargabe", start date:datum, end date:datum, allday event:true}
    end tell
end repeat
```

(note I had to rename my calendar)
If I put the date function in the calendar tell it fails, outside of it works... That work for you?